# when using shell_exec() function in PHP nothing happens

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, tcp

I am trying to execute the following command through PHP using `shell_exec()` function:

```
sudo -u USERNAME -pPASSWORD echo "SOME-STRING" > /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/64444
```

but nothing happens (if I copy/paste it manually to the terminal it works). There is also nothing in the `$output` of the `shell_exec()` function.

So with that command I am trying to send a string over TCP through a different user with sudo privileges.

EDIT #1: The full PHP command looks like this:

```
shell_exec('sudo -u USERNAME -pPASSWORD echo "RLSET|79-192.168.1.33-0-1" > /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/64444');
```

EDIT #2: I've also checked the `phpinfo()` function and `safe_mode is off` also the `shell_exec()` function is not on the disallowed functions list.

EDIT #4: My PHP PATH variable contains the following locations:

> /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin

I'm lost here, any and all help would be appreciated.

Comment: No this is being executed locally to a local server that is always listening for TCP connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scape your quotes put your full command path:

```
 shell_exec("sudo -u USERNAME -pPASSWORD echo \"FULL-PATH-COMMAND\" > /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/64444")
```

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific in my question. I was using apostrophes so the quotes don't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

maybe your binary (`sudo`, `echo`, ...) is not in the `PATH` env variable :

```
putenv('PATH', '/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:') // etc...
```

Comment: I tried adding you code on top of mine and nothing changed ... Is there any way I can debug what happens with shell_exec() ?

Comment: have you tried to write a simple command like `shell_exec('whoami')` and see if you have an output ?

Comment: Yes 'whoami' returned www-data. Simple commands like 'ls' work just fine and also return the $output.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting a space after -p?

So that should be

```
shell_exec('sudo -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD echo "RLSET|79-192.168.1.33-0-1" > /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/64444');
```

I just tried some commands here on my own machine.

I tried

```
sudo -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD ls
```

and it works but when I tried

```
sudo -u USERNAME -pPASSWORD ls
```

It give me the usage information.

Comment: That didn't change anything. I even tried it without the password but nothing happens.

Comment: Does this line alone work? echo "RLSET|79-192.168.1.33-0-1" > /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/64444'

Comment: If I manually copy it to the terminal it works yes but if I execute with PHP than no it doesn't work.